# How to find mail log

Tags: email, domain, icq

I have an old ICQ account that is attached to an old email. I don't know which email account it is, as ICQ just says my password was emailed to XXXXXX@mydomain.com.

I own that domain still, but it's on godaddy now (it used to be a freebsd server in my closet). Is there a way to check postmaster failures that are sent to my domain on Godaddy? I'm sure the ICQ site is sending requests for my username to the domain I own, but I don't know how to see that request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up postmaster (or a new account) to be a catch-all email account (anything that does not have a mailbox or alias or forwarder will be delivered to this account).  In this way it can send to anything@yourdomain.com and you will receive it.

Comment: That worked! I got the email. Now I can talk to my 1 friend on ICQ :/ lol thanks!